# How to call Javascript Function in Angular Js on click Event

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dom-events

I am trying to call Javascript Function in Angular Js on click Event..

**Here is the code for click event**

```
 listData += '<div class="col-sm-8 padding-left-0 word-wrap"><span class="pros-desc">' + desc + '</span>...<span></span><a href="#" class="redmre ProfilePreview" attr-Location='
        + data.FirmLocation + ' attr-Urlkey=' + data.Urlkey + ' value=' + data.FirmID + ' attr-firm="' + data.FirmName + '" attr-LoginId="'
        + data.LoginId + '">View Profile</a></div><div class="col-sm-1"></div><div class="col-md-4  gap-10"><button type="button" class="bttn btn-green-md btn-BTsm btn-block" onclick="mymodel(' + user + ',' + firm + ')" id="myBtn">GET IN TOUCH</button></div>';
```

**and here is Javascript function ..**

```
 function mymodel(user, firm) {
     
        id = user;
        name=firm;
    }
```

**and here is angular js code**

```
  var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
  app.controller("customersCtrl", function ($scope, $http, $window) {
     var a;  // user value must come over here
     var b;  // firm value must come over here
   }
```

I need user and firm value of Javascript function in my angular js controller but it's not working.
I don't have any other option like I can convert all code in Javascript or angular js, it's small piece of large code so I don't want to change anything else.

I have tried so many options but still it is not working so if anyone can help me out that will be great.

Comment: do you have errors ?

Comment: i don't have any error

Comment: Put alert() inside your function and tell me if hits.

Comment: Did yo try calling your `javascript` function using `$window.mymodel(a,b)` from your `controller`? If you want to provide it directly to `div` use `on-click` and not `ng-click` or have `ng-click` call a `function` inside your `controller` which will call the `javascript` function using `$window.mymodel()`

Answer (score 0):

```
<div ng-click="mymodel(user, firm)"></div>     
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller("customersCtrl", function ($scope, $http, $window) {                    
    $scope.mymodel = function(a,b){
       //do whatever you want to do with values..
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks bro...i have tried this ... it's not working because DOM elements are in java script as you can see

Comment: @amitsingh show how you're getting the markup shown in JS into the DOM.